# tap() isn't triggered in RXJS Pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, ngrx

I have to ways of doing the same thing, although I prefer the first one. But the first approach doesn't seem to work. (the `tap()` is not triggered)

```
// does not work
this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LayoutActions.Types.CHANGE_THEME),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    tap(() => {
        console.log('test')
    }),
);
// works
this.actions$.ofType(LayoutActions.Types.CHANGE_THEME).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('test')
});
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Imagine RxJS pipes like actual, physical pipes with a valve at the end. Each pipe will "modify" the liquid that is flowing through it, but as long as the valve at the end is closed, nothing will ever flow.

So, what you need, is to open the valve at the end. This is done by **subscribing** to the observable pipe. The easiest solution is:

```
this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LayoutActions.Types.CHANGE_THEME),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    tap(() => {
        console.log('test')
    }),
).subscribe(_ => console.log("water is flowing!"));
```

Comment: Never used pipe before and had the same problem as OP. Thank you so much, now the water flows!!! haha

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Comment: awsome answer. hell yeah.

Answer (score 8):

`pipe` creates new `Observable` thus you must asssign it and then subscribe to that isntance. In your case you are ommiting `pipe` return thus you end up with plain, unmodified `Observable` without any extra pipe actions.

Also remember that most likely you will have to subscripbe in order to `pipe` (and `tap`) to work.

try

```
this.actions$=this.actions$.pipe(
    tap(()=>console.log("First tap")),
    ofType(LayoutActions.Types.CHANGE_THEME),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    tap(() => {
        console.log('Last tap')
    }),
);

this.actions$.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('subscribtion')
});
```