# Migrating RXJS do() to tap()

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have an Angular app using RXJS 6 for my authentication. I have rxjs-compat installed so the following code still works. But I would like to learn how to refactor the code.

```
 auth$ = this.af.authState
  .do(next => {
     if (!next) {
      this.store.set('user', null);
      return;
    }
    const user: User = {
      email: next.email,
      uid: next.uid,
      authenticated: true
    };
    this.store.set('user', user);
});
```

I was able to update my app using the docs, wrapping each operator in a pipe(), which was kind of neat, but I noticed that I wasn't getting the Authstate updated in my store. So after a bit of research i found a reference [here from ggradnig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52188958/10648022).

I tried playing around with tacking on a subscribe after the pipe and I was able to console log out, but I couldn't figure out how to get the authenticated: true to trigger. Here's the tap() version I forgot to post that is not returning the authentication.

```
 auth$ = this.af.authState
.pipe(
tap(next => {
    if (!next) {
      this.store.set('user', null);
      return;
    }
    const user: User = {
      email: next.email,
      uid: next.uid,
      authenticated: true
    };
    this.store.set('user', user);

})
```

)

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your expectation correctly. Are you expecting `auth$.subscribe(next => console.log(next.authenticated))` to print out `true`? If yes then you need a `map` operator instead of `tab` operator. But if you are only expecting `authenticated: true` inside `this.store.set` method then what you have looks ok to me, as long as there is a subscribe on `auth$`.

Comment: The two source code examples do exactly the same thing. So it's not clear what you're asking. Are you referring to the `map()` operator?

Comment: The tap() version returns null whether the user is logged in or not. I don't have this issue with the do() version under rxjs.compat. So I think I'm missing a step in my refactor.

Comment: I figured it out. I was rebuilding the app and of course I forgot about my app.component. It was missing the subscribe.auth. Thanks for the help, checking for the subscribe really helped.