# Rxjs strange problem with BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm experiencing a curious behavior with BehaviorSubject in my angular (7) application.

I created a service which consumes some rest calls. To picture what's happening in the code here you are:

```
export class MyService {
    private dataFromServer = new BehaviorSubject<IDataFromServer[]>(null);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll(): Observable<IDataFromServer[]> {
        this.http.get<IDataFromServer[]>('/api/rest')
        .pipe(
            tap(data => this.dataFromServer.next(data))
        );
    }
    return this.dataFromServer.asObservable();
}
```

So far so good. When I need to consume this service, I subscribe to the getAll() method like

```
this.myService.getAll().subscribe(console.log);
```

and print the data to the console.

Now I have to add data from the frontend to the rest api

```
export class MyService {
    private dataFromServer = new BehaviorSubject<IDataFromServer[]>(null);

    // snip...

    add(item: IDataFromServer): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<IDataFromServer>('/api/manage', item).pipe(
            tap(data => {
                let internal = this.dataFromServer.getValue();
                if (!internal) {
                    internal = new Array<IDataFromServer>();
                }
                internal.push(material);
                this.dataFromServer.next(internal);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

This is where the trouble begins. The subscription above print the first time, but does not receive the new data triggered from next().

What is puzzling me is that if I hit refresh on browser, without changing any line on the code, the subscription get back to life every time I hit next().

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't understand why and where.

Thanks for any of your help.

Comment: Where is `add` called? please include this in your snippets

Comment: In your latter snippet, the fact nothing appears to subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject` seems suspicious.

Comment: it looks from your code that you subscribe to `add` method, not to `dataFromServer` since it's private and you will not be able to subscribe to it from inside..

Comment: it does, `getAll` seems to return the subject, however the braces must be misplaced in that function.

Comment: Without seeing it, I would guess that the result of `add` is not subscribed to. Therefore, `tap` is never called.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188795/tap-isnt-triggered-in-rxjs-pipe/52188958#52188958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with the great answers as to why your solution does not work, I will add my take on what it is wrong with your approach.

From what I see, you are trying to expose a single observable from your service that will be used on every REST call, allowing views to decouple and reuse data visualization logic from data update login (namely, they will just need to show data once and every time they update the data the same logic will be invoked).

The problem is that `httpClient` Observables are lazy, actually sending requests only if someones subscribes.

I have done the same thing and what I usually do is hiding http calls in my service and subscribing internally. Borrowing your classes, it would look like this:

```
export class MyService {
    private dataFromServer = new BehaviorSubject<IDataFromServer[]>(null);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll(): Observable<IDataFromServer[]> {
        this.http.get<IDataFromServer[]>('/api/rest')
                 .subscribe(data => this.dataFromServer.next(data));
        return this.dataFromServer.asObservable();
    }

    add(item: IDataFromServer): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<IDataFromServer>('/api/manage', item)
                        .subscribe(data => this.dataFromServer.next(data));
    }
}
```

I am also assuming your endpoint follows REST principles, so the `/api/manage` path returns as a response the full list updated with the new added data, just like a call to `/api/rest/` would return after the POST call.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you and thanks to @ggradnig for pointing me out to the right way of thinking about my error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you call `this.http.get<IDataFromServer[]>('/api/rest')` within `getAll` but no one ever subscribes to it.

The first log you mentioned must be `null` because you initialize your `BehaviorSubject` with null.

What you need to is to simply return `http.get` from `getAll` so anyone calls this method and subscribes to it will trigger the http call. Also, `tap` will make sure that your data in `BehaviorSubject` will be updated.

```
 getAll(): Observable<IDataFromServer[]> {
    return
        this.http.get<IDataFromServer[]>('/api/rest')
        .pipe(
            tap(data => this.dataFromServer.next(data))
        );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I add the return and removed the     return this.dataFromServer.asObservable(); as you suggested
does work the first time, but later updates still do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't include the part where you call the `add` function, I'm pretty certain that you don't subscribe to the result of it.

You might have a line of code that says something like

```
myService.add(myItem);
```

Now, this will return an Observable. Note however that if noone subscribes to that Observable, the attached pipes won't get triggered.

Therefore, you have two solutions.

First: Don't use `tap`, but subscribe. I'm almost sure this is what you want. It goes like this:

```
add(item: IDataFromServer): void {
    this.http.post<IDataFromServer>('/api/manage', item)
        .subscribe(data => {
            let internal = this.dataFromServer.getValue();
            if (!internal) {
                internal = new Array<IDataFromServer>();
            }
            internal.push(material);
            this.dataFromServer.next(internal);
        }
    );
}
```

Second: Subscribe to the result of `add`. Something like this:

```
myService.add(myItem).subscribe();
```

The problem results from a common misunderstanding about Observables. [Maybe this post helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188795/tap-isnt-triggered-in-rxjs-pipe/52188958#52188958).

Comment: If I subscribe to add(), I get the error that is not an observable.

Comment: You can do either the first or the second solution. If you want to subscribe to it (solution 2), then `add` needs to return the observable as seen in your original snippet.

Comment: You are right, and togheter with @bracco23 answer clarified to me my error. My only  regret I cant mark your comment the solution along the answer