# Code within RxJS pipe() not Being Executed

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

For the following code:

```
  public getExecution(modelId: string, reportId: string, params: ParameterSet | null): Observable<ExecutionToken> {

    return this.getNewExecution(modelId, reportId, params, null)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((token: ExecutionToken) => {
          return this.reportExecutionHubService.assignExecutionToClient(token).then(resolve => token);
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        tap((token: ExecutionToken) => this.updateExecutionTokenState(token))
      );
  }
```

I put a breakpoint on the line with the mergeMap(); but the breakpoint was never hit.

The breakpoint on the tap(...) line was hit; but `this.updateExecutionTokenState(token))` was not called - I put a breakpoint on the first line of     `private updateExecutionTokenState(token: ExecutionToken): void {` and that breakpoint was never hit.

```
  private updateExecutionTokenState(token: ExecutionToken): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new executionTokenActions.UpdateExecutionToken({ // breakpoint on this line
      reportId: token.reportId,
      executionSessionId: token.executionSessionId,
      executionRequestId: token.executionRequestId,
      modelRevisionId: token.modelRevisionId,
      dateReceived: token.dateReceived
    }));
  }
```

Likewise, for the following code:

```
  public get(payload: ReportExecutionRequest): Observable<ExecutionToken> {
    return this.apiService.postWithReturn<ReportExecutionRequestResponse>('reportExecution/', payload)
      .pipe(
        catchError((response: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> => {
          if (response.error?.code === this.SESSION_TIMEOUT_ERROR_CODE) {
            // this.store.dispatch(new modelActions.SetPageErrored(true));
            this.store.dispatch(new executionTokenActions.ExpireCurrentReportExecutionToken());

            // swallow the error
            return of();
          }

          return throwError(response);
        }),
        map<ReportExecutionRequestResponse, ExecutionToken>((response) => {
          if (payload.executionSessionId !== response.executionSessionId) {
            this.toastrService.info('toast_info_preparing_execution_session');
          }

          const token: ExecutionToken = {
            reportId: payload.targetSet,
            dateReceived: new Date(),
            executionSessionId: response.executionSessionId,
            executionRequestId: response.executionRequestId,
            modelRevisionId: payload.modelRevisionId
          };

          // this.reportExecutionLocalStorageService.add(token);
          this.store.dispatch(new executionTokenActions.AddExecutionToken(token));

          return token;
        })
      );
  }
```

I placed a breakpoint on the line:

```
if (payload.executionSessionId !== response.executionSessionId) {
```

which is just inside the map(), but again, the breakpoint was never hit.

How I am subscribing to the observable:

```
    this.reportExecutionFacadeService.getExecution(this.modelId, this.reportId, null).subscribe((token) => {
      console.log(token);
    });
```

I am using Chrome developer tools debugger if that helps - please let me know what I am not understanding here.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tap() isn't triggered in RXJS Pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188795/tap-isnt-triggered-in-rxjs-pipe)

Comment: Unfortunately not - I had
`this.reportExecutionFacadeService.getExecution(this.modelId, this.reportId, null).subscribe();`

Comment: Are you subscribing to the observables? It is difficult to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: Please see "How I am subscribing to the observable:" - near the bottom of my post.

Comment: this all could just be some bugs in your break point set up. put `console.log` statements in the functions instead. if it's logging, then the functions are being called. and you can narrow this down to an issue with your break points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If b breakpoint on the `mergeMap` is never hit, that means that your function `this.getNewExecution` in turn, is not emitting any value.

Make sure that the function `this.getNewExecution` returns any Observable type (Subject, BehaviorSubject, etc.) and that the observable emits a value.

Only when the Observable returned by `this.getNewExecution` emits, only then `mergeMap` inside the pipe would run.

BTW, you can write your code like so (no need to chain pipe twice):

```
public getExecution(modelId: string, reportId: string, params: ParameterSet | null): Observable<ExecutionToken> {

    return this.getNewExecution(modelId, reportId, params, null)
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((token: ExecutionToken) => {
                return this
                    .reportExecutionHubService
                    .assignExecutionToClient(token)
                    .then(resolve => token);
            }),

            tap((token: ExecutionToken) => this.updateExecutionTokenState(token))
        )
}
```

BTW2: It looks like `assignExecutionToClient` returns a promise. If you're looking to take the result resolved by the promise and merge it with the `getNewExecution` stream, its better to turn it into an observable like so (using `from` from 'rxjs'):

```
public getExecution(modelId: string, reportId: string, params: ParameterSet | null): Observable<ExecutionToken> {

    return this.getNewExecution(modelId, reportId, params, null)
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((token: ExecutionToken) => {
                return from(this
                    .reportExecutionHubService
                    .assignExecutionToClient(token)
                );
            }),

            tap((token: ExecutionToken) => this.updateExecutionTokenState(token))
        )
}
```

And of course, for the whole thing to actually run, you must subscribe to the returned observable. That is, in the calling function, you must write:

```
    someCallingFunction() {
        this.getExecution(modelId, reportId, params)
            .subscribe(token => console.log(token));
    }
```

Observables pipe will not run until they are subscribed to. So not subscribing to `getExecution` will not trigger the whole thing.

Comment: `mergeMap` and other high order observables treat promises as subscribable since v6 was released. but the observable you're looking for is `from` not `of`, `of` will convert `Promise<T>` into `Obersvable<Promise<T>>`, `from` will convert `Promise<T>` to `Observable<T>`

Comment: You're right, I modified the answer. Thanks.